# Torrent not installing

Tags: windows-10

Something's wrong with my laptop, when I try to install utorrent or any simmilar software like bittorrent it gives an error of no internet connect even when my laptop is connected to a proper internet connection.

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: According to my laptop's configuration, Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that upnp is enabled on router.

Here some more explanations - [How does Bittorrent work in peers behind Carrier-grade NATs](https://superuser.com/questions/1121652/how-does-bittorrent-work-in-peers-behind-carrier-grade-nats/1160307)